# Vector calculus triple integral question

Tags: calculus, integration

Looking to get some help with this triple integration question from my textbook.

$\iiint _D 3xydV$ where $D$ is the solid region above the xy-plane bounded below by the cone $ z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and above by the cylinder $x^2+z^2=1$

Comment: To find the bounds of integration, you need some inequalities which describe the region of integration.  Using the equations you have, take a stab at it.  You'll learn more by giving it a shot and checking.  Also, draw a picture.  That's always a good start.  Also also, is there any symmetry you can exploit to get simpler expressions (what non-Cartesian coordinate systems do you know?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Lazy Answer

The solid $D$ has symmetry in $y$; that is, for every point $(x,y,z)$ in $D$, the point $(x,-y,z)$ is also in $D$.

[image: solid D]

The integrand $f(x,y,z)$ is odd in $y$; that is, $f(x,-y,z) = - f(x,y,z)$ for all $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Putting these facts together, the integral is zero.  To see why, think about splitting $D$ into many pieces, and weighting the volume of each piece by the function value on that piece.  For every piece on one side of the $xz$-plane, there is a mirror image piece on the opposite side (this is because of the symmetry of $D$).  Moreover, the function value on that mirror image piece will be the exact opposite as on the original piece.  So in summing them, each piece and its mirror image will cancel in pairs.

### Smart Answer #1

To sketch the region, find the curve along which the two surfaces intersect.  If $x^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, we can square the second and substitute it into the first:
$$
x^2 + (x^2 + y^2) = 1 \implies 2x^2 + y^2 =1
$$
So the curve of intersection projects onto the ellipse $2x^2 + y^2 =1$ in the $xy$-plane.  This curve bounds a plane region $R$.

Over $R$, the two surfaces can be expressed as graphs of functions of $x$ and $y$.  The cylinder satisfies $z=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and the cone is $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ already.
Therefore
$$
    \iiint_D 3xy\,dV = \iint_R \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}3xy\,dz \,dA
$$
Now to integrate over $R$, we take the boundary curve $2x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and find the limits of $y$: $y= \pm\sqrt{1-2x^2}$.  The limits of $x$ are when $y=0$, so $x = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  Therefore
$$
    \iiint_D 3xy\,dV = \int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{1/\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\sqrt{1-2x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-2x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}3xy\,dz\,dy\,dx
$$

This integral looks complicated, but step by step the answer is revealed.  First, notice that $3xy$ is independent of $z$, so integrating with respect to $z$ means we just tack on a $z$:
$$\begin{split}
\int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{1/\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\sqrt{1-2x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-2x^2}} \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}3xy\,dz\,dy\,dx
&= \int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{1/\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\sqrt{1-2x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-2x^2}} 
\left[3xyz\right]^{z=\sqrt{1-x^2}}_{z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dy\,dx \\
&= \int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{1/\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\sqrt{1-2x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-2x^2}}
3xy\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\,dy\,dx \\
&= \int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{1/\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\sqrt{1-2x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-2x^2}}
3xy\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dy\,dx
- \int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{1/\sqrt{2}} \int_{-\sqrt{1-2x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-2x^2}}
3xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx
\end{split}
$$

At this point, notice that both integrals are of an odd function of $y$ over an interval $[-u(x),u(x)]$.  So again by symmetry, each evaluates to zero.  Or, you can continue to evaluate them directly; the second one needs a substitution $u=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

### Smart Answer #2

After writing the first “smart” answer, I realized there was a better way to harness the symmetry.  Instead of projecting onto the $xy$-plane, project onto the $xz$-plane.  The image of $D$ is the region
$$
    R_2 = \left\{(x,z) \mid |x| \leq z \leq \sqrt{1-x^2}\right\}
$$
and the limits of $y$ are $y=\pm\sqrt{z^2-x^2}$.  So now
$$
   \iiint_D 3xy\,dV = \iint_{R_2} \int_{-\sqrt{z^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{z^2-x^2}}3xy\,dy\,dA_{x,z}
$$
For any $x$ and $z$,
$$
\begin{split}
\int_{-\sqrt{z^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{z^2-x^2}}3xy\,dy
&= \left[\frac{3}{2}xy^2\right]^{z=\sqrt{z^2-x^2}}_{z=-\sqrt{z^2-x^2}}\,dy=0
\end{split}
$$
So
$$
\iiint_D 3xy\,dV = \iint_{R_2} 0\,dA_{x,z} = 0
$$

Comment: how do i go about setting up this triple integral?

Comment: okay so the integration of this breaks down to 0-0?

Comment: @mathhelpplease: yes.

Comment: awesome thanks for your time

Comment: smart answer #2 makes the most sense to me

Comment: I don't know that I agree with your labelling.  I always consider symmetry arguments that allow me to skip the computation to be the *smart* method.  Very good answer, though. +1

Comment: @Bye_World: I use *lazy* as a virtue: knowing when to get out of work (*smart* means being able to do the work).  This is my version of the [three programming virtues: laziness, impatience, and hubris](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris)